# How can I square each item of an integer array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying learn Kotlin.

I have an array: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

How can I print the squares of each of the numbers in the array?

For example in Python I could just do:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(" ".join (str(n*n) for n in array))
```

But I am not sure how to do this in Kotlin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [**map**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html):

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(array.map { n: Int -> n * n })
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `println(array.map{ it * it }) `

Comment: This answer introduces unnecessarily two functions (instead of one function): the first one is `n: Int -> n * n` and the second one is `x: Int -> first_one(x)`. The above comment using `{ it * it }` or more explicitly `println(array.map { n: Int -> n * n })` is better.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin you use [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(array.joinToString(separator = " ") { n -> "${n * n}" })
```

You can also use [`joinTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to.html) to join directly to a buffer (e.g. `System.out`) and avoid the intermediate `String`:

```
array.joinTo(System.out, separator = " ") { n -> "${n * n}" }
```